# About beamer-latex themes

Tags: beamer

I have a question about beamer-latex. I have just downloaded the beamer-latex from this cite: http://faculty.csuci.edu/jorge.garcia/tex/beamer.htm.

I did all the requirements. But some of the things do not work:

1. when I write a small code (without frametitles or subsection...), it gives a pdf file but gives theme error, it doesn't understand the theme if it it Warsaw or any others.
2. For long codes , the program doesn't give any pdf view and gives a lot of errors: theme error, frametitle error...

Could you please help me, if anyone understands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That download is really old: beamer class Version 3.06 of 2005-06-16, working with pgf 1.0. There can be many errors if you use it together with newer packages.

It's very recommendable to install a newer one, either with the package manager of your TeX distribution or download it from CTAN. The most recent version is 3.12, working with pgf 2.10.

- With MiKTeX, use the MiKTeX package manager aka `mpm` for installing, in the manager look for the [beamer package](http://miktex.org/packages/beamer).
- With TeX Live (Windows, Linux, Unix), use the TeX Live Manager aka `tlmgr`, with the GUI or `tlmgr install beamer` on the command prompt.
- With a derived Linux TeX distribution, look out for a beamer package of the Linux repositories, with the Linux package manager (Synaptic, rpm, YAST, ...)

Don't download it just from somewhere. If you really would like to download for manual installation, get the [beamer package](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) from the most reliable TeX archive: [CTAN](http://ctan.org).

Comment: Id like to add, that the most recent build can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/overview

Comment: @Esen Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank Stefan by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).